# kitchen downlights sometimes flicker or go out

Tags: lighting, kitchens

We moved into our new (to us) house 7 months ago and have been working our way through loads of issues (the previous owners let lots of things go to ruin). We're now on our kitchen downlights -- we have four, and two of them sometimes flicker, and also sometimes completely go out (they can flicker and then go back to normal, they can flicker and then go out, and sometimes they go out without flickering).

They are JCC Hybrid9 downlights (spares apparently, part number SPR94901) and replacements are no longer sold. Are the current lights salvageable, or is the flickering/turning off indicative of failing fixtures?

I'd also like to know how the lights get their power, since they don't seem to connect to anything except via the locking pins and a flat surface (with some soft of paste/cement -- thermal insulation maybe?). I've attached pictures of the lights if they'll help!

[image: Images of downlight]

Comment: do they flicker at the same time, or independantly?

Comment: They flicker completely independently.

Comment: Those lights had a 10 year warranty according to there web site. They were tool less installation so the twist lock sounds right. Going out independently I would look at the lights and if they are in a new 7 month home quickly get in touch with the builder. The fact that they are already not providing parts to me say they were real junk. Don’t waste time work on getting replacement fixtures I found there web site searching jcc hybrid 9 SPR94901.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @EdBeal. I've edited the question to indicate that the home is new to us, not new. We don't know when the lights were originally put it, but it seems a bit of a shame to bin them if they can be made to work correctly.

Comment: the lugs provide power and fastening. They are almost certainly dying. You can get new cans or pancakes for a few bucks these days anyway, life's too short to try and fix something so cheap...

Comment: Thanks @dandavis -- we're trying to minimise waste, and since the lights work sometimes (flickering/turning off maybe 50-70% of the time), we're trying to gauge if there's another thing (the ragged thermal(??) insulation, for example) to DIY before doing a swap. But we are _totally_ ready for a replace if that's the right solution.

Comment: Moneypitmatt As these fixtures may be beyond warranty and they are flickering and going out at different times on the same circuit I would say leave them until they totally fail if that is what you want, could it be loose connections? Sure but very doubtful. these fixtures draw very little power and the lower the power requirements are the less likely that a heating issue with a bad connection is the cause.